# Flutter FIrebase (instance.collection)

Tags: flutter

I got the error here

under

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(auth.currentUser.uid).setData({
                  'levelTestTaken': true,
```

please let me know why it's like that?
I tried to solve this problem. but couldn't find the solution.. I already imported firebase things. but it just says it's 'undefinded'. I don't know what is the problem essentially..

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'app/modules/auth_service/auth_controller/auth_controllers.dart';



void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/splash',
      routes: {
        '/splash': (context) => SplashPage(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
        '/level_test': (context) => LevelTestPage(),
        '/main': (context) => MainPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _navigateToAppropriatePage(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Container();
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _navigateToAppropriatePage(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    if (auth.currentUser == null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
    } else {
      DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(auth.currentUser.uid).get();
      bool levelTestTaken = userDoc.data['levelTestTaken'];
      if (levelTestTaken) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/main');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/level_test');
      }
    }
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Login Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class LevelTestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // Save the levelTestTaken information to the user's document in the Firestore database
            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
            await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(auth.currentUser.uid).setData({
              'levelTestTaken': true,
            }, merge: true);
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/main');
          },
          child: Text('Complete Level Test'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Main Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH7IO.jpg)

please check the image, and let me know

thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using a deprecated version of firebase. Try to look into the new documentation. This is the new website [flutter firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android) and not [old flutter firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)

```dart
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(auth.currentUser.uid).setData({
                  'levelTestTaken': true,
```

will change to

```dart
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

await db.collection('users').docs(auth.currentUser!.uid).set({'levelTestTaken':true});
```

If you need anything else, leave a comment below.

Comment: Thank you. I sovled it with [
            FirebaseFirestore auth = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
            await auth
                .collection('users')
                .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
                .set({'levelTestTaken': true});] but

Comment: [   DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(currentUser.uid)
          .get();]  here under 'Firestore' I still got the error

Comment: Check and confirm the user id with print()